# If I Infuse two weapons and one has Strength and Intellect, and the other has Strength and Discipline, what will happen?

Tags: destiny

What the title says. If I have Strength and Intellect, and fuse with a weapon that has Strength and Discipline, what will happen?

Comment: The question body is not just for show. Use it to further elaborate on your question's title. Simply repeating the exact same thing is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

When infusing the only stat that is carried through from the weapon you are using as infusion fodder is the light level. So if you infuse a weapon with strength and discipline into a weapon with strength and intellect the weapon will still have strength and intellect and it will have the light level of the strength and discipline weapon. The strength and intellect may also go up because they are related to the light level of the weapon.

Answer (score 0):

One, weapons don't have intellect, strength, and discipline stats.

Two, when you infuse a higher light armor piece into a lower light level piece, the ONLY thing that carries over is the light level.  Everything on the lower light level armor piece remains the same except the light level.